# Setting pyautogui time to points of a second i.e. 0.5s

Tags: python, pyautogui

using pyautogui I am controlling my web browsers scrolling by running the below program:

import pyautogui

```
pyautogui.time.sleep(3)

while 0 < 10: 
  pyautogui.scroll(-25)
  pyautogui.scroll(0.2)
```

I would like for `pyautogui.scroll(0.2)` to be fired every 0.2s however upon testing get erros unless I am using a whole number.

How can is use decimal numbers for the amount of time the scroll function is fired? so it is fired every 0.2s as an example

---

The aim of using this, is to have my browser scroll down the screen (smooth scroll if possible - please DO NOT SUGGEST JS this is not viable)

---

The ulimate goal of this which I am building towards is to have the browsers scroll from the top of the page to the bottom over 25 seconds (smoothly if possible), if you have any suggestions on how the above code could be modified to achieve that goal that would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance -
W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not found a way to fire the program at decimal numbers i.e. 0.2s however - as for how to make the program scroll down the page smoothly:

`pyautogui.click(button='middle')` to simulate the user clicking the middle button.

`pyautogui.position()` to get the current mouse position, this can be modified with .y or .x to get the specific mouse location of the X or Y.

`pyautogui.moveTo(X, Y)` to move the mouse

In other words, click middle mouse, find the current mouse position (add 50px to the Y to make the mouse move down).

```
pyautogui.time.sleep(3)  //this stop the program from running for 3 seconds so you can move the mouse into position
print(pyautogui.position().y)

pyautogui.click(button='middle')

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, pyautogui.position().y + 50)
```